# Self-inductance, back EMF and energy stored in magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

First let's talk about self inductance. A current-carrying loop produces a magnetic field which in turn produces a flux through the loop. If this current is increased, the flux changes as the magnetic field changes and this creates a back EMF $\epsilon$ which opposes the change in current. I have heard that the work we do against this back EMF to get the current going is the energy which is stored in the magnetic field.

My doubt is what should I consider my system.
For example, if I assume my *system* to be 'a unit moving charge $Q$ under force of the battery creating a current'. Thus, initially, my system is the steady current which is under a constant EMF $\epsilon_0$ which is causing it to move. Now on increasing the value of the current, back EMF acts on the current and opposes it. The work done by battery to maintain the current is equal and opposite to the work done by this back EMF.

The net force acting on the current is zero.
Thus, $∆KE$ is zero.

And, $W_{battery} = - W_{back\ emf} = ∆U?$
Is this correct?

Comment: Your first paragraph is fine, but after that it gets hard to follow. You talk about a 'steady current' whose value can be increased. So it's not steady. You talk about 'the work done by us'. Do you mean the work done by the battery? The distinction between your two 'systems' is not clear – to me at least. You seem to be determining your systems by whether or not you are counting particular forces as acting. This is not how we distinguish between systems. Maybe you could re-word? And have you remembered that in a real circuit there will be resistance, against which work is done?

Comment: I understand, I edited the paragraph. Please take a look and comment!

Comment: Work is also done against resistance so, **per unit charge**, $W_{batt}-W_{back} =IR$

Comment: Considering an ideal conducting wire with no resistance, the $W_{batt}=W_{back} $. Will this $W_{batt}$ be equal to the potential energy stored in the magnetic field of the moving charge? (As we increased current, magnetic field changed inducing electric field which caused the back emf)